# how to fix Overflow in turtle rotation

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I was trying some code with turtle (just for fun) and I got surprised when I tried:

```
import turtle
turtle.speed(0)
for i in range(0,100):
    for x in range(0,i):
        turtle.forward(5)
        turtle.left((2**x)*90)
```

this worked normally as expected untill around i = 98 when it suddenly glitched
[image: Glitch]
this shouldnt be happening as it is always multiplied by 90 so it should alway be a right turn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system the glitch starts after iteration 50.  The problem seems to be the difference between big integers, which the program is using, and floats, which turtle is using.  If we instrument the code:

```
angle = 0

for i in range(55):
    for x in range(i):
        turtle.forward(5)
        turtle.left(2**x * 90)
        angle += 2**x * 90
        print(angle % 360, turtle.heading())
```

Everything starts out great:

```
90 90.0
180 180.0
0 0.0
90 90.0
270 270.0
```

But eventually floating point imprecision starts to accumulate:

```
270 269.2593644676
270 269.0124859568
0 359.0124859568
180 179.0124859568
180 179.0124859568
```

And accumulate:

```
270 258.1498314817
270 254.1997753089
0 344.1997753089
180 164.1997753089
180 164.1997753089
```

And eventually flies out of control:

```
90 42.5993259266
90 26.7991012355
180 116.7991012355
0 296.7991012355
0 296.7991012355
```

As @alexelias notes, we can use modulus to get around the problem, by providing turtle with a value that accumulates less imprecision over time:

```
turtle.speed('fastest')

for i in range(100):
    for x in range(i):
        turtle.forward(5)
        turtle.left((2**x % 4) * 90)
```

Rather than modulus the entire value by 360, we know that `360 / 90 == 4` so we just modulus the other value by 4.

Comment: thanks it really worked and just so you know I found something interesting, if you change the 2 to any other number it changes between 4 diferent paterns quite cool

Comment: also try instead putting x^x instead of 2**x

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import turtle
turtle.speed(0)
for i in range(40,100):
    for x in range(0,i):
        turtle.forward(5)
        turtle.left((2**x*90)%360)
```

using modulo will limit the output to 359

#### Edit:

the operation was overflowing in the `turtle` library, [not your script](https://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html). So you can safely modulo the operation before you send it to turtle.

Comment: This could become a good answer if you explained _why_ the glitch happens in the original code and _why_ and _how_ your code fixes this.